# Stored function computes incorrect value

Tags: mysql, function

I have a function that should return the value of only one element, but this is returning from every table

```
Function verify(idAluno INT) returns INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE teste INT;
    SELECT COUNT(status) into teste FROM listapresenca WHERE idAluno = idaluno;
    RETURN teste;
END
```

The values from the listapresenca is

```
idAluno status  horario
1       ENTROU  2018-09-02 21:46:25
0       NAO     2018-09-02 21:46:43
0       NAO     2018-09-02 21:46:45
0       NAO     2018-09-02 21:46:46
0       NAO     2018-09-02 21:46:48
0       NAO     2018-09-02 21:59:10
```

The result from putting the variable idaluno = 1 should be 1, but it is returning 6.

if I use outside the function `SELECT COUNT(status) FROM listapresenca WHERE idAluno = 1`, the return value is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a clash between the column name `idAluno` in the table and the parameter name `idAluno` in the function, so your `WHERE` clause is effectively comparing the same values and will return all data from the table (hence your result of 6). Try changing the parameter name to e.g. `searchId`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION verify(SearchId INT) returns INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE teste INT;
    SELECT COUNT(status) into teste FROM listapresenca WHERE idAluno = SearchId;
    RETURN teste;
END
```

Then you can test with:

```
SELECT verify(1), verify(0)
```

Output (for your data)

```
verify(1)   verify(0)   
1           5
```

Demo on [Rextester](http://rextester.com/DVB31262)

Comment: this did not work, when i put the id value i am looking for it still returns 6

Comment: @GuilhermeSeibertZulian I'm not sure why that should be, you can see from the demo link that it does work. Did you `DROP` the old function first?